# Erasing everything on my current I phone besides contacts

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, contacts, restore

I would like a fresh start and want to delete everything on my iPhone but still keep my current contacts. I just want all of my photos, notes, and everything else to be backed up on iCloud. I just logged into my iCloud account and it looks like everything is there which is good. I just do not know how to clear all the data on the phone and then ONLY get my contacts back on the phone.
Any help would be appreciated and I hope ya'll have a good day. TIA!!

Answer (score 2):

Unless there’s a compelling reasons to not take the easy route:

1. ensure the iCloud backup is complete for all data
2. Restore the contacts after erasing all content and settings.

For 10,000 contacts, this takes about 10 minutes in my experience in the US. You might need more time to backup and restore the further away from Apple data centers you are, but contacts are very small amounts of data to back up and then restore.

When you sign in again after erasing the device, just don’t sign in to iCloud when asked. Skip it from the setup assistant screen.

Sign in later from the settings app so you can control and turn off all the items except contacts.

Comment: My pleasure. This trick is handy for pruning one set of data, then re download the rest later.